# Detect language in my url

Tags: php, regex

I have a url and I want to detect the language to save it in the cookies.
This is my url :

```
https://www.example.com/en/test.php
```

Comment: you want to get /en/ part from your URL?

Answer (score 2):

There are different methods to do it:

**1. Method A (explode REQUEST_URI):**

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /en/test.php
$exp = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // explode by slash
$language = $exp[1]; // first element before / (slash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the current url (without serveur) :

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   // gives "/en/test.php"
```

Then explode it in an array :

```
$urlParts = explode ('/', $url); // split the url by /
```

The first element (index 0) is empty (because the string starts with `/`), and the language is the second one (index 1)

```
$language = $urlParts[1] ;
```

Don't forget to check at each steps if the url is OK and the arrayx contains more than 1 element.